# Null pointer exception while getReadableDatabase

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-service

I know I'm asking this question again but I tried several solutions on SO and other websites but to no rescue.
I am getting NULL pointer Exception while trying to get readable instance of database though my database is created viz visible through DDMS view.
Plz help

Please let me know if something else is required

LOGCAT :

```
02-28 01:28:56.585: ERROR/NewContactTrackService(285): Adding to instant upload database contact id 21
02-28 01:28:56.595: ERROR/NewContactTrackService(285): Added to instant upload database contact id 21
02-28 01:28:56.615: ERROR/Net UNAVAILABLE details stored in buffer(285):  Sd
02-28 01:28:58.186: ERROR/NetworkReceiver(285): onReceive: connected, starting UpdaterService
02-28 01:28:58.186: ERROR/NewContactTrackService(285): UPDATE CALLED
02-28 01:28:58.186: ERROR/NewContactTrackService(285): INSIDE IF
02-28 01:28:58.186: ERROR/NewContactTrackService(285):  qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
02-28 01:28:58.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.gooogle.omcsa.NetworkReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2646)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3100(ActivityThread.java:119)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:193)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at com.gooogle.omcsa.NewContactTrackService.update(NewContactTrackService.java:185)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at com.gooogle.omcsa.NetworkReceiver.onReceive(NetworkReceiver.java:21)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2637)
02-28 01:28:58.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(285):     ... 10 more
02-28 01:28:58.275: ERROR/dalvikvm(285): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
02-28 01:28:59.635: ERROR/ActivityThread(52): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
```

NETWORK RECEIVER

```
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { //
public static final String TAG = "NetworkReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
boolean isNetworkDown = intent.getBooleanExtra(
ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
if (isNetworkDown) {
Log.e(TAG, "onReceive: NOT connected, stopping UpdaterService");
//context.stopService(new Intent(context, UpdaterService.class)); //
} else {
Log.e(TAG, "onReceive: connected, starting UpdaterService");
NewContactTrackService networkTrack= new NewContactTrackService();
networkTrack.update();

Log.e(TAG, "onReceive: connected,uploading ");
//context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdaterService.class)); //
}
}

}
```

NewContactTrackService: To make it short I've posted only relevant part of service

```
public class NewContactTrackService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        dbBuffer = new DbContactBuffer(this);
        dbInstantBuffer = new DbInstantBuffer(this);
        values = new ContentValues();
        instantupload=0;
        isInstantUploadEnabled =  this.getSharedPreferences("isEnabled", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        isDataForInstantUpload=false;
        Log.e(TAG,"onCreate");  
    }

public void update()
 {
  Log.e(TAG,"UPDATE CALLED");
  Log.e(TAG,"INSIDE IF");
  dbInstantBuffer = new DbInstantBuffer(this);
  Log.e(TAG," qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq");
    db1 = dbInstantBuffer.getReadableDatabase(); //THIS IS THE LINE OF EXCEPTION     
    Log.e(TAG," wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww");
    cursor = db1.query(DbInstantBuffer.TABLE, null, null, null, null, null,null); 
    //startManagingCursor(cursor); 
    Log.e(TAG," "+ cursor.getCount());          
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {                       
                            //SOME CODE
    }
    db1.close();          

 }               
}
```

Comment: Most important part of your code is missing: `DbInstantBuffer`

Answer (score 0):

You define `dbInstantBuffer = new DbInstantBuffer(this);` twice in the onCreate and in update method. Moreover, I do not see the declaration of dbInstantBuffer (how and where it is defined).